# How should I trigger an XHR on component MouseClick using CalmmJS and React?

Tags: reactjs, reactive, kefir.js, calmm

What I want is to trigger an `XHR.perform` onMouseClick, using CalmmJS and React - I'm trying the following code, unnecessary parts redacted:

```
const getResults = someArg => XHR.perform({
    timeout: 60 * 1000,
    responseType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    url: U.string`/api/${ facet }/end-point/`,
    body: U.stringify( someArg )
});
...
<SomeElement
    ...
    onMouseClick={ U.ifElse(
            shouldMakeXHR, /* Atom that runs its own debounced XHR checks, then
                              runs it through an R.equals to see if the result
                              is acceptable - result is either true or false */
            _ => getResults( someArg ),
            R.identity //as no-op
    ) }
/>
```

Currently I'm just trying to trigger the network request, not do anything with the result. Instead the `XHR.perform` just gets swallowed without a trace. What am I doing wrong?

PS: Please could someone tag my post with karet or karet.util, as I am unable to create tags. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another basic one that I just kept banging my head against for some reason.

The answer is to not use a regular function, but to take advantage of the `karet.util` library and <s>`U.doPush` a value to a `U.bus()` stream. The [official CalmmJS documentation](https://github.com/calmm-js/karet.util#bus) actually points you to a [really clear and simple example demonstrating this behaviour](https://codesandbox.io/s/1840p9xo9l).</s> <s>`U.doSet` a value to a regular `U.atom()`,</s> although I'm starting to think there must be a better way...will update this answer if I find it.

There is a better way! Straight from Vesa Karvonen/@polytypic himself:

```
const requestsBus = U.bus()

const xhrProperty = XHR.perform(U.toProperty(requestsBus)) 

<button
  onClick={U.doPush(requestsBus, {
        timeout: 60 * 1000,
        responseType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        url: U.string`/api/${ facet }/end-point/`,
        body: U.stringify( someArg )
})}>
  Request!
</button>
```

Here's the original almost-working code, for posterity -
**DO NOT USE THE CODE BELOW THIS LINE - SEE ABOVE**

```
const mouseClick = U.atom( false );
const makeRequest = someArg => XHR.perform({
timeout: 60 * 1000,
responseType: 'json',
method: 'POST',
url: U.string`/api/${ facet }/end-point/`,
body: U.stringify( someArg )
});
const getResponse = U.when( mouseClick,
    XHR.responseFull( makeRequest( someArg ) );
...
<p>{ U.stringify( getResponse ) }</p>
<SomeElement
...
    onClick={ U.ifElse(
        shouldMakeXHR, /* Atom that runs its own debounced XHR checks, then
                          runs it through an R.equals to see if the result
                          is acceptable - result is either true or false */
        U.doPush( mouseClick, true ),
        R.identity //as no-op
) }
/>
```

Note that this will continue to make XHR post requests whenever someArg changes after the first mouse click.